# How can i refresh only nuxt component in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

i want refresh my component after add something. İ try

```
  refresh() {
    this.$nuxt.refresh()
  }
```

this but not working this is truelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my idea to refresh the component. Base on your issue, you can use some ways to achieve this goal. But in my opinion, there is a way that you can bind a `key` to your component, and by changing the key, your component will refresh.

I implement a simple example to show you how it works:

```js
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button @click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    component_key: 0
  },
  methods: {
    refreshComponent() {
      this.component_key += 1
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="refreshComponent()">
Refresh Compoenent
</button>
  <button-counter :key="component_key" />
</div>
```

You can click on the right button in the above example and see the count is going up. After that, when you click on the `Refresh Component` button, you see that the component refreshes.

Also, you can use `this.$forceUpdate()` to refresh all of your variables. Maybe it'll help with your situation, but I recommend the `key` binding solution for your issue.